# Which part of speech is "to get a thing" a part of?

Tags: parts-of-speech, parsing

Consider the following sentence:

> We had to go to get a book.

This is how I identify each word or group of words to its corresponding part of speech:

- `We` is the subject of the sentence.
- `had` is the auxiliary verb, the sentence is in past tense. The sentence could end here and it is still grammatically correct.
- `to go` is an infinitive acting as an adverb modifying the verb `had`. The sentence could also end here and still be grammatically correct.
- `to get a book` this is my question. How should I dissect this? If the sentence ends at `to get` a person would ask "to get what?" so the noun `a book` is a restrictive component to the word `to get`. Is this an infinitive phrase? A compound noun? I don't think it is a preposition either. Did I wrongly approach this structure?

Comment: You can't analyse it like that. "To go" is not a constituent, and in any case it would not be a modifier of "had". "A book" is object of "get".

Answer (score 3):

> *We had* [*to go* [*to get a book*]].

Preliminary point: most speakers treat stative "have" as a lexical verb, but some treat it as an auxiliary.

The sentence consists of a main clause (the sentence as a whole) and two embedded subordinate clauses, as bracketed.

"Have" is a catenative verb and the subordinate clause "to go to get a book" is its complement.

The second subordinate clause, "to get a book", is a purpose adjunct in clause structure. "A book" is object of "get".

Answer (score 2):

*"Have to"* is used in the sense of *"must"* to mean something is *obligatory*. *"Must"* is an auxiliary verb; but *"have"* is a main verb.

e.g., I *must* do it. (Subject + auxiliary verb + main verb + object)

= I *have to* to do it. (Subject + main verb + to-infinitive)

I *will* *have to* do it (Subject + auxiliary verb + main verb + to-infinitive).

> "We had to go to get a book."

Here, **had** is not an auxiliary verb.

We = subject

had = main verb

to go = to-infinitive

(had to go = were obliged to go.)

to get a book = infinitive phrase showing *purpose*.

Comment: It's worth noting that *in principke* there's no limit to the number of "infinitive phrase showing purpose" elements that can be chained together in such contexts. *We had to go **to get** a book **to give** to him **to help** him pass his exam **to go** to university...* Personally, I'd also add that for many if not most native speakers, ***had*** here would be pronounced ***hat*** (and the Present.Tense versions written ***has / have*** would be enunciated with a "hard s / f" as ***hass / haff***).

Comment: Exactly. We can use such "infinitive phrases showing purpose" one after another / successively.

Comment: "Have" is an auxiliary verb for some speakers.

Comment: *"We **have** gone there".* Here, *"have"* is an auxiliary verb. *"We have to go there".* Here, *"have"* is a main verb.

Comment: No: In "We have to go there", "have" can (for some speakers) be an auxiliary verb. The difference becomes apparent in interrogatives. Auxiliary  "have" inverts with the subject ("Have we to go there?"), while lexical "have" requires _do_ support ("Do we have to go there?").

Comment: *Have to is NOT an auxiliary verb (it uses the verb have as a main verb).*  https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modals-have-to-must-not.htm